# Android Plugin in Eclipse Luna

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Luna in my system but I couldn't find any path to android project.I tried File->New->Project and I couldn't find android project.

Comment: Have you installed ADT Plugins??

Comment: go to help -> eclipse market and install ADT plugin. then you can see Android project.

Comment: why you still use eclipse ?

Comment: Then wat else ur using? @amorenew

Comment: Android Studio it's the official Android IDE by Google

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html it will give you all environment for android or you want add plugin in eclips

then follow this
To add the ADT plugin to Eclipse:

```
1.Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2.Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3.In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Note: The Android Developer Tools update site requires a secure connection. Make sure the update site URL you enter starts with HTTPS.
Click OK.
4.In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
5.In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
6.Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

7.6If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
8.When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```